# How to add wms tilelayers in a layer group

Tags: leaflet

I want to add a tile layer on top of a map in a layer group which can be turned on and off. I found an example in leaflet website which works find for a layer group but if I add wms layer in a layer group then it does not work. Here is an example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Layers Control Tutorial - Leaflet</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og==" crossorigin=""></script>


    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #map {
            width: 600px;
            height: 400px;
        }
    </style>


</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>

<script>
    var cities = L.layerGroup();

    L.marker([39.61, -105.02]).bindPopup('This is Littleton, CO.').addTo(cities),
    L.marker([39.74, -104.99]).bindPopup('This is Denver, CO.').addTo(cities),
    L.marker([39.73, -104.8]).bindPopup('This is Aurora, CO.').addTo(cities),
    L.marker([39.77, -105.23]).bindPopup('This is Golden, CO.').addTo(cities);


    var mbAttr = 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        mbUrl = 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw';

    var grayscale   = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'mapbox.light', attribution: mbAttr}),
        streets  = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'mapbox.streets',   attribution: mbAttr});

    var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [39.73, -104.99],
        zoom: 10,
        layers: [grayscale, cities]
    });

    var baseLayers = {
        "Grayscale": grayscale,
        "Streets": streets
    };

    var overlays = {
        "Cities": cities
    };

        var nexrad = L.tileLayer.wms("http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cgi-bin/wms/nexrad/n0r.cgi", {
        layers: 'nexrad-n0r-900913',
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true,
        attribution: "Weather data © 2012 IEM Nexrad"
    });

    L.control.layers(nexrad, baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

If I add  `nexrad` in

```
L.control.layers(nexrad, baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
```

then it doesn't work. What is the correct way to add wms layer in a layer group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't need to be in a layer group (although it can be) - add the `layer` to the `overlays` array like this

```
var overlays = {
        "Cities": cities,
        "Nexrad": nexrad
};
```